# How to know which contextual embedding to use at test time

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, embedding

Models like BERT generate contextual embeddings for words with different contextual meanings, like 'bank', 'left'.
I don't understand which contextual embedding the model chooses to use at test time? Given a test sentence for classification, when we load the pre-trained bert, how do we initialize the word (token) embedding to use the right contextual embedding over the other embeddings of the same word?

More specifically, there is a convert_to_id() function which converts a word to an id? how does one id represent the correct contextual embedding for the input sentence at test time? Thank you.

I searched all over online but only found explanation about the difference between static vs. contextual embedding, the high level concept is easy to get, but how is that really achieved is unclear. I also search some code example, but the convert_to_id() makes me further confused as I asked in my question.

Comment: Maybe https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ would be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** There's only one embedding for the word "left." There's also no way to know which meaning the word has if the sequence is only one word. BERT uses the representation of it's start-of-sequence token (i.e., `[CLS]`) to represent each sequence, and that representation will differ depending on what context the word "left" is used in.

Given your example of text classification, the input sentence is first tokenized using the WordPiece tokenizer, and the `[CLS]` token's representation is fed to a feedforward layer for classification.

You can't really debate context when given single words, so I'll use two different sentences:

1. I left my house this morning.
2. You'll see my house on your left.

The steps to performing text classification typically are:

1. Tokenize your input text and receive the necessary `input_ids` and `attention_masks`.
2. Feed this tokenized input into your model and receive the outputs.
3. Feed the `[CLS]` token's representation to a classifier layer (typically a feedforward network).

The two sentences are tokenized to (using `bert-base-uncased`):

1. `['[CLS]', 'i', 'left', 'my', 'house', 'this', 'morning', '.', '[SEP]']`
2. `['[CLS]', 'you', "'", 'll', 'see', 'my', 'house', 'on', 'your', 'left', '.', '[SEP]']`

The `[CLS]` token's representation for each sentence will be different because the sentences have different words (i.e., contexts). The result is therefore different.

```
>>> from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
>>> bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
>>> tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
>>> sentence1 = "I left my house this morning."
>>> sentence2 = "You'll see my house on your left."
>>> sentence1_inputs = tokenizer(sentence1, return_tensors='pt')
>>> sentence2_inputs = tokenizer(sentence2, return_tensors='pt')
>>> sentence1_outputs = bert(**sentence1_inputs)
>>> sentence2_outputs = bert(**sentence2_inputs)
>>> cls1 = sentence1_outputs[1]
>>> cls2 = sentence2_outputs[1]
>>> print(cls1[0][:5])
... tensor([-0.8832, -0.3484, -0.8044,  0.6536,  0.6409], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
>>> print(cls2[0][:5])
... tensor([-0.8791, -0.4069, -0.8994,  0.7371,  0.7010], grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed example. In your example, BERT should learn different embedding for 'left' in the embedding space give the two different meanings. In the input layer, there is an embedding input too, ignore the positional embedding for now, how do we set those input word embedding for the word 'left' at test time given different sentence may have different meaning for 'left'?

Comment: @Veydan I'm not sure I understand 100% what you mean by "set those input word embeddings for the word 'left' at test time." Do you mean that you want to use a different embedding value than what you trained your model on? If you insist on it then all you have to do is set `BertEmbedding.word_embedding(id_for_left)` to another tensor value. Why would you want to do that though?

Comment: Hi, @Sean, I am curious what kind of embedding does this `BertEmbedding.word_embedding(id_for_left)` load given 'left' is polysemy? in general, when we load a pretrained BERT for fine tuning, what do we load for the input embeddings? also the `convert_to_id()` assigns one unique id for a word, but if the word is polysemy, is one id enough to represent different meanings? Thank you.